# How do I get a working progress bar for inputs given to GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to figure out how to get GNU Parallel to display a progress bar, but so far it isn't working.  Basically, I want to add a progress bar to this:

```
parallel -j5 -k sh /home/user/scripts/test.sh ::: samplehost1 samplehost2 samplehost3 samplehost4 samplehost5
```

I would like some sort of progress bar to increment after the script has finished on each host (i.e. parallel runs and finishes the script on samplehost1, bar increments to 20%, when samplehost2 finishes, 40%, etc)   Parallel's built in progress bar is weird, and doesn't seem to work for my use case.

Additionally, I would like said progress bar to dynamically know how many inputs I have (note, these will be hostnames usually, so not easily incremented in a normal counter).

I played with using pv, but I can't seem to make it work correctly (bar sits at 0% and never moves, even when the scripts are progressing normally).  I am extremely novice in bash, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why GNU Parallel's --bar does not do what you want? It is supposed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: If you `really` cannot use `--bar` then maybe you can parse the output: `parallel --bar -j5 -k 'sleep 1; echo {}' ::: samplehost1 samplehost2 samplehost3 samplehost4 samplehost5 u i n 2> >(perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="\r"};/^(\d+(.\d+))/ and print "$1\n"; $1 == 100 and exit')`

Comment: from what I can tell, --bar has a couple of problems I haven't been able to circumvent.  1) the first part of the bar (from 0%) doesn't read the execution time correctly, it just sits at 0% 0.0s until the first job completes, then it increments to 20% and then starts accurately timing.  2) as the output from each job finishes and prints to the screen, the bar sections end up getting split between each print section, thus the appearance of a bar is lost.

Comment: I suppose I could make --bar work if I could stall parallel from generating output until all jobs were completed, but --wait appears to only work in sem mode

Comment: How would you be able to predict anything before the first job finishes? Regarding output: Be aware that the output from `--bar` is on stderr and most jobs output on stdout: parallel --bar seq ::: {1..1000} | wc

Comment: What I mean is there anyway to keep parallel from printing output to the screen until ALL jobs finish... I don't care if the jobs are output somewhere else during the run, as long as at the end the output from all jobs is combined and printed to the screen.

Comment: Like this? `seq 1000 | parallel --bar echo > out; cat out`